# How can I run valgrind with --leak-check=full in child processes?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I wrote a program that sometimes leaks in its child processes. To try to figure out why, I run

`valgrind --leak-check=full --trace-children=yes ./shell`

The `--leak-check=full` works correctly on the parent process, but it is explicitly not applied to any child processes. For example,

```
==14044== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14044== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14044== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14044== Command: ./shell
==14044== 
Shell by: user
(pid=14044)/home/user/user/shell$ invalid_command --flag-that-is-ignored
Command executed by pid=14044
invalid_command: not found
==14046== 
==14046== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14046==     in use at exit: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==14046==   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 15 frees, 552 bytes allocated
==14046== 
==14046== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14046==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14046==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14046==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14046==    still reachable: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==14046==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14046== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==14046== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==14046== 
==14046== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14046== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
(pid=14044)/home/user/user/shell$ exit
==14044== 
==14044== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14044==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14044==   total heap usage: 26 allocs, 26 frees, 845 bytes allocated
==14044== 
==14044== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14044== 
==14044== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14044== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

As you can see, when I call `invalid_command` from within my program, it correctly sees that `invalid_command` is not a command and prints an error accordingly. This child process then cleans up and exits, and valgrind prints out a leak summary. But the leak summary says `rerun with: --leak-check=full` despite the fact that I *did* run it with that flag!

When I exit the parent process, I have no memory leaks and it appears that `--leak-check=full` applied to the parent process correctly.

How can I make `--leak-check=full` apply to the child processes that I create? The program is written in C and I'm just using the normal `fork(); exec(); wait();` paradigm.

Comment: Can you not read the output of `valgrind --help`?  Try `--help` with almost any program.  It usually gives some help (though some require just `-h` for the job).  If that fails, give a bogus option (I usually use `-:`) and see what the usage message says.  That would have answered your question.  You desire to track children is perfectly sane and reasonable — but not using the facilities right in front of you (or checking the [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) web site and the manuals there) is remiss of you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, I forgot to mention that I've tried running `valgrind` with `--trace-children=yes` in addition to `--leak-check=full`, but it still does not apply to the children. Whenever I a child exits, I get the same output as above.

Comment: That was rather important missing information. Please update the information in the question showing the command line and output from a run with the option in effect.  (With that information, your question becomes much more reasonable.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following combination of options solved my problem:

`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --trace-children=yes ./shell`

If any of these are omitted, the output will be as shown above (it will not include line numbers).

Comment: Glad you got the answer you were looking for. Sometimes the problem isnt what you think it is at first is it? It appears that it wasnt that you werent tracking the children, but rather you were telling valgrind not to display the leaks that the children were producing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `--trace-children=yes` option.

Comment: I thought so too, but this gives me the same output as above.